# Preprocessing a video in android for pytorch

Tags: android, kotlin, computer-vision, pytorch, video-processing

What is the best way to preprocess video data in Android Kotlin, in preparation to feed into a PyTorch Android model? Specifically, I have a ready-made model in PyTorch, and I've converted it to be ready for [PyTorch Mobile](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/).

During training, the model takes in raw footage from phones and is preprocessed to (1) be greyscale, and (2) compressed to a specific smaller resolution that I have specified, (3) converted to a Tensor to be fed into a neural net (or potentially send the compressed video to a remote server). I use OpenCV for this, but I'm wondering what the easiest way to do this would be in Android Kotlin?

Python code for reference:

```
def save_video(filename):

    frames = []

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
    frameCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    buf_c = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))
    buf = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth), np.dtype('uint8'))

    fc = 0
    ret = True

    # 9:16 ratio
    width = 121
    height = 216
    dim = (width, height)

    # Loop until the end of the video
    while fc < frameCount and ret:
        ret, buf_c[fc] = cap.read()

        # convert to greyscale
        buf[fc] = cv2.cvtColor(buf_c[fc], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # reduce resolution
        resized = cv2.resize(buf[fc], dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        frames.append(resized)
        fc += 1

    # release the video capture object
    cap.release()

    # Closes all the windows currently opened.
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return frames
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that your model was converted to be ready for PyTorch Mobile so I will assume that you scripted your model with TorchScript.

With TorchScript, you can write preprocessing logic using Torch operation and keep it inside the scripted model like this:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

@torch.jit.script_method
def preprocess(self,
               image: torch.Tensor, # This should have format HxWx3
               height: int,
               width: int) -> torch.Tensor:
    img = image.to(self.device)

    # (1) Convert to Grayscale
    img = ((img[:, :, 0] + img[:, :, 1] + img[:, :, 2]) / 3).unsqueeze(-1)

    # (2) Resize to specified resolution
    # Mimic torchvision.transforms.ToTensor to use interpolate
    img = img.float()
    img = img.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
    img = F.interpolate(img, size=(
        height, width), mode="bicubic", align_corners=False)
    img = img.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0)
    # Then turn it back to normal image tensor

    # (3) Other normalization like mean substraction and convert to BxCxHxW format
    img -= self.mean_tensor  # mean substraction
    img = img.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
    return img
```

So all the preprocess will be done by `libtorch`, not `opencv`.